# Azure DevOps - How do I create a build pipeline using more than one repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When creating a new Build Pipeline, the first stage is to select a repository.

I want to create a build for a Java project on one repository, but also include imports and configurations that reside on a different repository (Both are Azure Repos Git).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Microsoft added this feature (in Sprint 161) and if you use YAML pipeline you can clone multiple repos in this way:

```
resources:
repositories:
 - repository: tools
   name: tools
   type: git

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: tools
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout).

---

*(The old answer)*

Currently you can't specify more then one repository in the "Get Sources" phase.

There is a [Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365522/allow-tfs-build-to-depend-on-multiple-repositories.html) about it and the status is `On Roadmap`.

You have 2 options:

1) Git solution - create the second repository as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the first repository. then in the "Get Sources" you can check the checkbox `checkout submodules`, then Azure DevOps will bring the two repositories into the agent.

[image]

2) Azure DevOps solutuin -  add a Command Line or a PowerShell task that bring the second repository to the agent with `git clone second-repo-url`.

[image]

Comment: Hello, when I run `git clone <url>`. It shows `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://abc.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled`. How to fix this